# Eliminar datos duplicados de un array de objetos tomando de referencia otro array de objetos en JS

Tags: javascript

buenas tardes, tengo un problema que no he podido resolver, tengo 2 array de objetos, uno es un catalago de identidades permitidas, y el otro array tiene algunos valores de esas identidades permitidas, el problema que tengo, es que quiero un nuevo array eliminando los valores iguales en ambos arrays... ejemplo

```js
let catalogoIdentidades = [{id: 1, name: 'INE'}, {id: 2, name: 'ACTA DE NACIMIENTO'}, {id: 3, name: 'CURP'}, {id: 4, name: 'BOLETA'}, {id: 5, name: 'LICENCIA DE MANEJO'}, {id: 6, name: 'CREDENCIAL DE TRABAJO'}, {id: 7, name: 'OTROS'}];

let identidadesPermitidas = [ {id: 5, name: 'LICENCIA DE MANEJO'}, {id: 6, name: 'CREDENCIAL DE TRABAJO'}];


//resultado esperado
// NUEVOARRAY = [{id: 1, name: 'INE'}, {id: 2, name: 'ACTA DE NACIMIENTO'}, {id: 3, name: 'CURP'}, {id: 4, name: 'BOLETA'}, {id: 7, name: 'OTROS'}];
```

No se si me doy a entender, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

[Filtras](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `catalogoIdentidades` con la condicion que no existe en `identidadesPermitidas` usando [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let catalogoIdentidades = [{id: 1, name: 'INE'}, {id: 2, name: 'ACTA DE NACIMIENTO'}, {id: 3, name: 'CURP'}, {id: 4, name: 'BOLETA'}, {id: 5, name: 'LICENCIA DE MANEJO'}, {id: 6, name: 'CREDENCIAL DE TRABAJO'}, {id: 7, name: 'OTROS'}];

let identidadesPermitidas = [ {id: 5, name: 'LICENCIA DE MANEJO'}, {id: 6, name: 'CREDENCIAL DE TRABAJO'}];

let result = catalogoIdentidades.filter(a=> !identidadesPermitidas.some(b=>a.id==b.id));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes dos arreglos de objetos:

```
var catalogoIdentidades   = [{id: 1, name: 'INE'}, {id: 2, name: 'ACTA DE NACIMIENTO'}, {id: 3, name: 'CURP'}, {id: 4, name: 'BOLETA'}, {id: 5, name: 'LICENCIA DE MANEJO'}, {id: 6, name: 'CREDENCIAL DE TRABAJO'}, {id: 7, name: 'OTROS'}];
var identidadesPermitidas = [{id: 5, name: 'LICENCIA DE MANEJO'}, {id: 6, name: 'CREDENCIAL DE TRABAJO'}];
```

Y deseas comparar sus valores, ignorando duplicados, puedes emplear [esta solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904924/9443618) de `S_i_l_e_n_t C_o_d_e_r`:

```js
var catalogoIdentidades    = [{id: 1, name: 'INE'}, {id: 2, name: 'ACTA DE NACIMIENTO'}, {id: 3, name: 'CURP'}, {id: 4, name: 'BOLETA'}, {id: 5, name: 'LICENCIA DE MANEJO'}, {id: 6, name: 'CREDENCIAL DE TRABAJO'}, {id: 7, name: 'OTROS'}];
var identidadesPermitidas  = [{id: 5, name: 'LICENCIA DE MANEJO'}, {id: 6, name: 'CREDENCIAL DE TRABAJO'}];

var resultado = catalogoIdentidades.filter(item1 => ! identidadesPermitidas.find((item2) => item1.id === item2.id));

console.log(resultado);
```

Se trata de filtrar los elementos del primer arreglo con el método [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) donde por cada elemento realizas una búsqueda en el segundo arreglo empleando el método [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Si `find` no se evalúa es porque el segundo arreglo no contiene ese elemento que si contiene el primer arreglo, entonces, no está duplicado.

Answer (score 1):

Eso puedes conseguirlo de la siguiente manera:

```
let result = catalogoIdentidades.filter(identidad => {
    return !identidadesPermitidas.some(permitida => identidad.id === permitida.id);
 });
```

El codigo te hace un filtrado de *catalogoIdentidades* y te devuelve las que poseen un id que no se encuentra ni siquiera en algun elemento de *identidadesPermitidas* (traduciendote casi literal lo que quiere decir el código).